# MethodNotAllowedHttpException when using PUT and DELETE method in Laravel form

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am working on basic CRUD using Laravel. I am getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException when using PUT and DELETE method in Laravel form action. GET and POST action methods work fine.

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you're doing?

Comment: post some code,so we can help you out

Answer (score 7):

HTML form only accept either `GET` or `POST` method so you can't use `PUT` and `DELETE` in form method. However, if you want to use `PUT` or `DELETE` then laravel provide `Form method spoofing` like this

`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`

Here is the form example

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Short form

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::put('foo/bar', 'FooController@bar');
```

Check details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing